# Error when mining with MacMiner

Tags: mac, mining-software

I am super new and I understand none of this. I am using MacMiner (the recent version). I opened up the FPGA/ASIC Miner and I get this error when I try to run it.

```
    [2021-04-15 15:05:52] Timers: Using clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW)
 [2021-04-15 15:05:52] Global quota greatest common denominator set to 1
 [2021-04-15 15:05:52] setrlimit: Changed soft fd limit from 4864 to 1024 (FD_SETSIZE=1024; hard limit=unlimited)
 [2021-04-15 15:05:52] Started bfgminer 5.5.0-unknown
 [2021-04-15 15:05:52] Loaded configuration file /Users/ (I am taking this out since it is my name ) /Library/Application Support/MacMiner/bfgurls.conf
 [2021-04-15 15:05:52] DISPLAY not set, setting :0 just in case
 [2021-04-15 15:05:52] CL Platform 0 vendor: Apple
 [2021-04-15 15:05:52] CL Platform 0 name: Apple
 [2021-04-15 15:05:52] CL Platform 0 version: OpenCL 1.2 (Jan  5 2021 23:17:05)
 [2021-04-15 15:05:52] Platform 0 devices: 1
 [2021-04-15 15:05:52]  0   Intel(R) Iris(TM) Graphics 6100
 [2021-04-15 15:05:52] Unable to load ati adl library
 [2021-04-15 15:05:52] Probing for an alive pool
 [2021-04-15 15:05:52] Testing pool stratum+tcp://us-east.stratum.slushpool.com:3333
 [2021-04-15 15:05:52] HTTP request failed: Protocol "stratum+tcp" not supported or disabled in libcurl
 [2021-04-15 15:05:52] Failed to connect in json_rpc_call
 [2021-04-15 15:05:52] initiate_stratum with sockbuf=0x0
```

How would I fix this? I understand none of this.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the source of the problem is this line

> HTTP request failed: Protocol "stratum+tcp" not supported or disabled in libcurl

[libcurl](https://curl.se/libcurl/) is a library (developed for the command-line "curl" program that can be used to fetch web-pages).

I suspect the most likely way to fix your problem is by updating MacMiner to the latest version and by checking that your computer also has the latest version of the libcurl library (using whatever package manager is appropriate for your computer)

I'm not familar with MacMiner or slushpool but you may also be able to configure MacMiner to use HTTP instead of STRATUM+TCP?